# Проблема с автозаполнением зависимых фильтров

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеются три фильтра. Первый это главный. и Два, который зависят от него. Пока в Первом фильтре ничего не выбрано, Двое следующих задизейблены.

Необходимо описать функцию, где при выборе Первого фильтра одного из "option" к примеру "Стулья" или "Столы" или и то и то одновременно, т.к. тут мультиселект, чтобы во второй фильтр и в третий фильтр пропадал дизейбл и подгружались различные "option. К примеру: При выборе "Диваны" , второй фильтр раздизейбливался и в него подгружались такие опции, как: Кожаный, Тканевый, Экокожа, Деревянный. И в третий фильтр подгружались такие опции, как: Угловой, Прямой, П-образный, Раздвигающийся и т.д. И в конце, нажав на кнопку "Найти" выводилась таблица.

```
<div class="form-group" id="FirstFilter">
    <label for="" class="col-lg-4 control-label text-right">Первый фильтр:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <select id="" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="first">Стулья</option>
            <option value="second">Столы</option>
            <option value="three">Диваны</option>
            <option value="four">Кресла</option>
            <option value="five">Кровати</option>
            <option value="six">Холодильники</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="secondFilter">
    <label for="" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Зависимый от первого фильтра:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <select id="" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" disabled>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="thirdFilter">
    <label for="" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Зависимый от первого фильтра: </label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <select id="" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" disabled>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
   </div>
</div>

<button id="btnFind" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-yellow"> Найти</button>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что не получается написать такую функцию(